# Retrieving child class with reflection from parent class in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

In the following code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyChild x = new MyChild();
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class MyParent
    {
        protected static void TestFunction()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        }
    }

    class MyChild : MyParent
    {
        public MyChild()
        {
            TestFunction();
        }
    }
}
```

I want the static method to output "ConsoleApplication1.MyChild" since that's the calling type.  Is this possible?  I can't find it anywhere in the reflection objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with a static method, since you are not *really* calling it on an instance of `MyChild`.  It will always only ever be called on `MyParent`.

Note that this probably won't even work if you make the method non-static, since you are asking what type *declares* the method that is executing, which is actually the parent class (the child class does not declare the method, it just inherits it).

However, if you make the method non-static, you will have access to the `GetType()` instance method, which will return to you exactly the type you want.